# convert multidimensional array to arraylist vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array, arraylist

Like the question asks I'm trying to convert this array into a multidimensional arraylist.

I know this can convert a single dimensional array to an arraylist but mine is mwarray(0-alot,0-1)

```
table = New ArrayList(mwaray)
```

Comment: The equivalent of a multi-dimensional array would be a list of lists. Also you should use List instead of ArrayList.

Comment: i need arraylist for google charts

Comment: Do you want to flatten the multi-dimensional array values into a single `ArrayList`?

Comment: no because one column hold all the time values ie. 'date' and the other holds the value for that time.

Comment: And ultimately, what do you want in the final ArrayList? If you don't tell us what you're trying to do precisely, it's hard to help you.

Comment: Ultimatlely i'm trying to pass the arraylist to the javascript on the asp page. This is the javascript I'm trying to incorporate. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Example

Comment: I'm still not sure how the data in the multi-dimensional array relates to the data in the ArrayList. Should each item in the ArrayList be an array of two items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to take all values from the multi-dimensional array and put it into a single `ArrayList`, then you can just loop through the values and add them:

```
table = New ArrayList()

For i as integer = 0 to mwarray.GetLength(0) - 1
    For j as integer = 0 to mwarray.GetLength(1) - 1
        table.Add(mwarray(i,j))
    Next
Next
```